# How to design the system which executes two process independently with different configuration?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, multithreading, abstract-class

I have two process `ProcessA` and `ProcessB`. I want to run these two process independent of each other. There is no relation between them at all.

- Each process should have a different Properties object.
- Each process should have a different thread  pool configuration since they can be run in multithreaded way if needed independent of other process.

Below is my design:

**Process class (abstract):**

```
public abstract class Process implements Runnable {
  private final Properties props;
  private final String processName;

  public Process(String processName, Properties props) {
    this.processName = processName;
    this.props = props;
  }

  public abstract void shutdown();
}
```

**ProcessA class:**

```
public class ProcessA implements Process {

  public ProcessA(String processName, Properties props) {
    super(processName, props);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // add run code here
    // all the logic of executing my process comes here
    // here it uses "processName" and "props" object to do certain things
  }

  @Override
  public void shutdown() {
    // shut down code
  }
}
```

**Process B class:**

```
// similar to `ProcessA` but with specific details of B
```

**ProcessHandler class (abstract):**

```
public abstract class ProcessHandler {
  private final ExecutorService executorServiceProcess;
  private final List<Process> processList;
  private final int poolSize;

  protected ProcessHandler(int poolSize) {
    this.executorServiceProcess = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
    this.processList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.poolSize = poolSize;
  }

  public void postInit(Process process) {
    for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; i++) {
      processList.add(process);
      executorServiceProcess.submit(process);
    }
  }

  public void shutdown() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        for (Process process : processList) {
          process.shutdown();
        }
        executorServiceProcess.shutdown();
        try {
          executorServiceProcess.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**ProcessHandlerA class:**

```
public class ProcessHandlerA extends ProcessHandler {

  public ProcessHandlerA() {
    super(3);// configure pool size properly w.r.to ProcessA
  }

  public void postInit() {
    ProcessA processA = new ProcessA("processA", properties);
    super(processA);
  }

  public void shutdown() {
    super.shutdown();
  }
}
```

**ProcessHandlerB class:**

```
// similar to ProcessHandlerA but with specific details for B
```

Below is my main class in one of my project where I execute my `ProcessA` and `ProcessB`.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
@DependencyInjectionInitializer
public class Initializer {

  @Inject
  private ProcessHandlerA processHandlerA;

  @Inject
  private ProcessHandlerB processHandlerB;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    processHandlerA.postInit();
    ProcessHandlerB.postInit();
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutdown() {
    processHandlerB.shutdown();
    processHandlerB.shutdown();
  }
}
```

And in some other project my main class will be:

```
public class Initializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // call both processes from here
  }
}
```

Is this the right design for this kind of problem? Let me know if there is any better and efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: Add more background. Launching tasks is trivial, what do you need to achieve?

Comment: They all are Kafka consumers listening to Kafka and on those events I do all kind  of manipulations and all these things happens in my run method of each process and after that I send it to some other system.

Comment: BTW, name process is misleading, yours are not native processes.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I just wanted to make problem simpler for design that's why I made it like that. As you can see in my abstract class `ProcessHandler` I have shutdown method which will shutdown all my processes.

Comment: Why a single pool won't do? You could add both tasks there to avoid extra management.

Comment: I want to run these two  process independent of each other. And each process can be run in multithreaded way if needed. And bcoz of that reason I have separated that out as well.

Comment: Processes in a single pool would only interfere if they schedule additional tasks into their pool. A single pool of size large enough to fit both process groups seems to be an obvious solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49207/discussion-between-david-and-basilevs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more suited for Code Review.

Your solution is fine, but you overuse inheritance and DI. Adding a process constructor argument to ProcessHandler and removing postInit method, would make ProcessHandler permanently consistent and prevent a need of extending it for each new Process.

```
public final class ProcessHandler {
  private final ExecutorService executorServiceProcess;
  private final Process process;

  public ProcessHandler(Process process, int poolSize) {
    this.executorServiceProcess = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
    this.process = process;
    for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; i++) {
      executorServiceProcess.submit(process);
    }
 }
  public void shutdown() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        executorServiceProcess.shutdown();
        process.shutdown ();
        try {
          executorServiceProcess.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
@DependencyInjectionInitializer
public class Initializer {

  // Use named injections, optionally
  private final ProcessHandler processHandlerA = new ProcessHandler (new ProcessA(), 3);
  private final ProcessHandler processHandlerB = new ProcessHandler (new ProcessB(), 3);

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutdown() {
    processHandlerB.shutdown();
    processHandlerB.shutdown();
  }
}
```